# CheckBoxPreference и отображение DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment, android-preferences

Имеется экран настроек, в котором при нажатии на CheckBoxPreference появляется DialogFragment для ввода пароля.

Проблема в том что когда происходит поворот экрана и CheckBoxPreference закрыт, то он все равно создается и отображается. Что может вызывать данную проблему? спасибо за помощь.

```
public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    private CheckBoxPreference checkPass;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        checkPass = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pass_enabled");

        checkPass.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (checkPass.isChecked()) {
                    DialogFragment newFragment = PasswordDialogFragment.newInstance();
                    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);
        findPreference("text_size").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
                preference.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.textSize) + o.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });
        findPreference("pass_enabled").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

                return true;
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: Поясните проблему: как я понял, вы нажимаете на CheckBoxPreference, показываете диалог, закрываете его и после этого повернув экран диалог снова сам собой открывается?..

Comment: Да, Вы все правильно поняли.
я попробовал запустить тот же диалог в активити. Тот же результат, при закрытии диалога и повороте экрана происходит появление диалога.
Мне же необходимо что бы диалог пере создавался, только в том случае если он не был закрыт.

Comment: Не знаю насколько правилен мой подход. но как я понял нужно сделать вложенный static class.
Во всяком случае это решило мою проблему.

Comment: Если вы решили вашу проблему, то можете опубликовать решение как ответ - это может быть полезно другим посетителям сей страницы, у коих будет похожая проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код фрагмента настроек. Создаем *public **static** class MyDialog*, который в свою очередь наследуется от `DialogFragment`.

```
public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    private CheckBoxPreference checkPass;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        checkPass = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pass_enabled");
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);
        findPreference("text_size").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
                preference.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.textSize) + o.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

        findPreference("pass_enabled").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

                if (!checkPass.isChecked()) {

                    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
                    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }


    public static class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

        public static MyDialog newInstance() {
            MyDialog frag = new MyDialog();
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null);
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancle", null);
            // Остальной код
            return builder.create();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, это дополнение к вопросу или решение?

Comment: Это является решением

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, поможет возвращение `true` из метода `onPreferenceClick`

Comment: здравствуйте. К сожалению это не помогло.